# php session variables wierd behaviour

Tags: php, session, variables

I am setting a session variable in PHP as follows:

```
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
```

where `$pass` is some password, ie. `"test4;"` The session variable on the left side works fine, but I found to my surpise and concern that `$pass` on the right side also seems to be a session variable, that is, once set, I can echo `$pass` from any page and it seems to persist until I destroy the session.

What gives? How can I prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, where does `$pass` come from?

Comment: Are you running with [register globals](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) enabled?

Comment: Maybe somewhere you assign session variable to `$pass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is probably on - which is a huge security risk! Check to see if this is the case, and make sure it's off. Also, it's a deprecated method.

If register_globals is enabled, you can [turn it off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) either by changing this setting in php.ini *OR* by placing this in a .htaccess file:

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

Comment: Where would I find this?  The site is hosted remotely on a shared server but I have access to some settings.

Comment: `phpinfo();` - it tells you all you need to know.

Comment: yes register globals is on.  Do you know how to turn it off, ie in what file?

Comment: I am getting an Internal Server Error

Comment: Update: adding the above flag to the htaccess file caused php to stop working.  However, my host lets you edit the php.ini file in the control panel and there is a setting to turn register_globals from on to off.  This did the trick and solved problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning the session and the $pass to be equal to each other.  Try just using

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['pass']))
```

With whatever information you want to validate

Comment: I really don't get what this has to do with OP's question? He's talking that is $pass (not his $_SESSION['pass']) is available everywhere.